# combining multiple matices one column at a time

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have three matrices called Matrix 1, Matrix 2 and Matrix 3 (all have equal number of rows and columns). I need to combine them into one matrix (NM) but with the columns in a different order, so:

```
NM column 1 = 1st column of matrix 1
NM column 2 = 1st column of matrix 2
NM column 3 = 1st column of matrix 3
NM column 4 = 2nd column of matrix 1
NM column 5 = 2nd column of matrix 2
```

and so on...

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy

```
M = vertcat(Matrix1, Matrix2, Matrix3);
M = reshape(M, size(Matrix1, 1), []);
```

Comment: Incredible - can't believe the solution is only two lines... I've spent half a day trying to do it with nested for loops!

Comment: Or you can even combine them into _one_ line! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
 NM=reshape ([M1; M2; M3], size (M1, 1), []);
```